# How to solve this 1st-order linear ODE system with a few discrete eigenvalues?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method, eigenvalues, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am trying to solve the eigensystem of a 1st-order linear ODE system in the region $(-\infty,\infty)$ and with Dirichlet boundary condition at the infinities 
$$
-i\partial_xu(x)+f^*(x)v(x)=\lambda u(x)\\
f(x)u(x)+i\partial_xv(x)=\lambda v(x)
$$ 
where $f(x)$ is a complex-valued function mainly varying around $x=0$ and $f^*(x)$ is its complex conjugate. I define $f(x)$ by its norm and phase in the code, where I give two forms of $f(x)$ (using Tanh or Lorentzian) of the similar profile.
I tried reducing it to a 2nd-order ODE. But unfortunately, it messes up the eigenstructure, i.e., $\lambda$ appears in several terms. 
I have no idea if it can be solved analytically.

It is known that the system will have a few (at least one) discrete real eigenvalues in $(-1,1)$ and the eigenfunction is more or less localized around $x=0$. Outside $(-1,1)$, there will be a continuous spectrum with probably not quite confined eigenfunctions. I am interested in the eigenvalue(s) in $(-1,1)$ only.

The code below gives 4 solutions but some eigenfunctions are very saw-tooth like. Therefore, I want to make sure if these solutions are true or spurious and if any other way to solve it reliably.

> {0.0856771, -0.169612, -0.881437, 0.94686}

```
a = 1; b = 0.8 a; c = 1; Nless = 8; cutoff = 20;
xR = cutoff; xL = -cutoff;
f[x_, pm_] = (a + b (Tanh[x/c - 1] - Tanh[x/c + 1])/(2 Tanh[1])) Exp[
    I pm \[Pi] (Tanh[x/c] + 1)/2];
(*f[x_, pm_] = (a + b (-c^2)/(x^2 + c^2)) Exp[
    I pm \[Pi] (Tanh[x/c] + 1)/2];*)
Fop1[F_] := D[F, x];
variables = {u, v};
lhs = {-I Fop1[u[x]] + f[x, 1] v[x], I Fop1[v[x]] + f[x, -1] u[x]};
bc = DirichletCondition[
   Table[component@x == 0, {component, variables}], True];
{vals, funcs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{lhs, bc}, {u[x], v[x]}, {x, xL, xR}, Nless, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" \
-> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001, "MeshOrder" -> 2}}}}];
vals
Table[Plot[
  If[iband <= Nless, Norm, _]@funcs[[iband, ab]], {x, xL, xR}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Small], {ab, {1, 2}}, {iband, 1, 
  6}(*,{part,{Norm(*,Re,Im*)}}*)]
```

Comment: The short answer is yes, i think the 0.0856771 value is spurious and the other three are fine. I'll hopefully post an answer using my package later.

Comment: I don't really know why NDEigensystem gives these spurious roots. The Evans function has a double root at zero here, in a similar way to your previous question, that could be part of the reason.

Comment: @KraZug I notice a weird behaviour. Your package doesn’t give any solution if I change $\pi$ even by a tiny bit in the phase factor of $f$ while `NDEigen` still produces some solutions. Any remedy or reason? Thanks.

Comment: The Evans function becomes complex for real values of $\lambda$, so `Plot` won't show anything unless you use `ReIm` or `Abs`. Or use `ContourPlot` or just `FindRoot`.

Comment: @KraZug I just use `FindRoot` and it gives nothing when I set $\pi$ to $1.1\pi$ in the phase factor. Does your answer give any solution for this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96140/discussion-between-xiaohuamao-and-krazug).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a package for solving eigenvalue boundary value problems using the Compound Matrix Method with the Evans function, which I'll use here. The package is available on [my GitHub](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod) (which has a notebook with examples), more details are in my other [answers to questions here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=compoundmatrixmethod), and a good introduction to the method is in [this pdf](https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~xl/FYB-background.pdf).

Install and load the package:

```
PacletInstall["CompoundMatrixMethod", 
     "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/Repository/master"];
Needs["CompoundMatrixMethod`"]
```

First write the system in the form $\mathbf{y}' = \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{y}$ using the function `ToMatrixSystem`:

```
sys1 = ToMatrixSystem[Thread[lhs == λ {u[x], v[x]}], {}, {u, v}, {x, -L, L}, λ]
```

Note by not giving boundary conditions the requirement is that $\mathbf{A}$ tends to the decaying behaviour of $\mathbf{A}_{\pm \infty} =\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \mathbf{A}(x)$. This will only work when there is a negative (resp. positive) eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}_{\infty} (\mathbf{A}_{- \infty})$. Here the eigenvalues become imaginary for real (not complex) values outside (-1,1):

```
Plot[Evaluate[Eigenvalues[Limit[sys1[[1]], x -> ∞]]], {\[FormalLambda], -1, 1}]
```

[image]

and `Evans` will fail without explicit boundary conditions at those points. *This method may be wrong to apply here, I think I need to consider further whether that is only applicable for higher order differential equations (e.g. a second order ODE in one variable).*

The Evans function is an analytic function whose zeroes correspond to eigenvalues, so we can plot that and look for roots:

```
Plot[Evans[λ, sys1 /. L -> 10], {λ, -0.99, 0.99}, 
 Epilog -> Point[{#, 0} & /@ vals]]
```

[image]

It looks initially like all 4 of the `NDEigensystem` values are roots, but if we zoom in we can see that there is a double root at zero, so the value at $0.0856771$ is spurious:

[image]

The winding number of the circle with radius 0.99 is 5, showing there are no further eigenvalues with $|\lambda|<=0.99$. The double root at zero is contributing two to the count here.

```
PlotEvansCircle[sys1 /. L -> 10, ContourRadius -> 0.99, nPoints -> 1000, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Note that providing explicit boundary conditions in gives very similar results, except for the eigenvalue at zero.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems that your links point to wrong content. Could you please check them again?

Comment: @Pinti Ah sorry, I copied those from a previous post but forgot to include the links. Duh. Edited them.

Comment: @Pinti, if you have any questions regarding my package I'm more than happy to discuss them.

Comment: @KraZug, thank you for the provided link. I read your answers and the Introduction by Fu to the method, which is useful! However, I have difficulty to understand Eq.(16) in that Introduction. As can be seen after integration the argument of the exponential does depend on $d$ since it is the integral limit, so why Evans function $D(\lambda)$ is independent of $d$? Btw, do you have the ref. Chadwick(1976) in that document, as I tried to read it, I found no item in the Reference...

Comment: @Nobody, I'm not entirely sure what that Chadwick reference is.  It'll definitely be Peter Chadwick, might be his book on elasticity but with the wrong year. The reference is just being used for the general matrix/tensor inequality, rather than Evans function specific. But if you take the equation (16) and differentiate with respect to , using the formula given in (17) and (18), then you can show that $\partial D/\partial d = 0$, and hence $D(\lambda)$ is independent of the matching point $d$.

Comment: @KraZug thank you for your reply! By searching, I guess it should be this book: Continuum Mechanics: Concise Theory and Problems by Peter Chadwick.

Comment: @Nobody Yes, that one. Although as I said it is only used for the formula with the trace. If you want to drop me an email (check my github package page) I can send you a work-in-progress expansion of Prof. Fu's explanation. Although I haven't done anything on it for about 18 months.

Comment: @KraZug Sorry for waking up this thread. Still this problem. But I found a weird result. Maybe a bug? Could you please take a look at [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112106/room-for-xiaohuamao-and-krazug)?